# Synonym for "pissed off"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Can anyone help me find a little bit more polite way to say "I am pissed off at you"?

I know this is used to show anger or irritation, but this is bit harsh.

So, do you have any other option?

Comment: Nothing will get someone so pissed off as telling him "I am pissed off at you" -- it's not really harsh at all, when used in the right context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some more possibilities:

> I'm ticked off at you.
>
> I'm teed off at you.
>
> I'm upset with you.
>
> You've really irked me.
>
> I'm peeved about this.

Answer (score 11):

You can say

> I'm angry with you.

or

> I'm annoyed at what you did.

or

> What you did bothered me a great deal.

or any number of things.

By the way, if you *do* want to use pissed off, use *at*, not *to*, for the preposition:

> I am pissed off at you.

or even just

> I'm pissed at you.

Comment: Isn't the last American? In UK pissed without the off means drunk. Also I would add: You (or your actions) piss me off...

Comment: @mplungjan: Although pissed is a euphemism for drunk (along with an almost infinte selection of more delightfully obscure ones), almost any Brit would understand that to be pissed *at* someone is to be angry at them.

Comment: Doesn't British English use "pissed up" to mean _drunk_?

Comment: I've only heard of a piss-up - meaning a party where the aim is to become drunk

Comment: I'm with mplungjan on that one - I've not heard of "pissed up", but a *piss up* is indeed a party as described.

Comment: @mplungian, @Andy F: Let's not get into a pissing match over this. The OP clearly is asking about the American sense of the term ("to show anger or irritation"), and I thought it made sense to confine my reply to that context.

Comment: @Robusto: Fair play, I suppose we did get a bit off topic. Apologies.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in Australia "to piss off" also means "to depart". "I was so pissed off with the boss that I pissed off to the pub."

Comment: To piss off means to depart in the UK too. Telling someone to piss off is another way of telling them to go away.

Comment: Pissed up does mean drunk in the UK. "They got pissed up on cheap booze".

Answer (score 5):

I am ... with you. Not at you.

> **I am annoyed/ticked off/angry/pissed off with you!**

Saying

> I am annoyed/ticked off/angry/pissed off at you!

suggests more aggression any an ambiguity as to whether the listener well be covered in urine.

---

> It is better to be pissed off than to be pissed on.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for less intense feeling:

I'm irritated.

I'm bothered.

However, synonyms for 'pissed off' should really communicate the full fury of the phrase, so I'd recommend:

I'm livid.

Answer (score 2):

- I am irritated with you
- I am cross with you
- I am mad at you

Answer (score 2):

I was really pissed off at someone the other day so after fuming in private and thinking about it for a bit I told the person in a calm yet firm manner what I was pissed off about (I had condensed it to about 12 words) and then I said (calmly yet firmly-rather matter-of-factly) "I am not at all happy about this." So now, when I'm pissed off at someone, that's what I'm going to say.

Comment: That sounds really stilted to me. I might even find it funny if someone says that to me.

Comment: @Mohit That might depend where you are. To a Brit. *not at all happy* is a polite but very firm/strong way of saying you are extremely displeased with a situation.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm annoyed with you", or "I'm angry".

Answer (score 1):

You could say you were *[dischuffed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dischuffed)*, a useful word that was common a while ago, but seems to be disused now.

Comment: Never heard that expression - but I would certainly understand it!

Answer (score 1):

I just recently used "royally miffed", even though harsher, more vulgar words were more appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

I am *irked* with you. Short. Efficient. Conveys the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm seething at you" though if the object of your ire is obvious, "I'm seething" on it's own can be stronger.

Comment: Seething: That's a good word for pissed.

Answer (score 0):

I always liked *fuming* ~ He was absolutely fuming when he found out ~ I wouldn't use it formally though.

Answer (score 0):

Do not say "I am pissed off" rather "I am disappointed in you" slowly and with heartfelt sadness. Anyone with a conscious knows if they did wrong will take this comment to heart, listen and remember. Being a disappointment is hard in life.

Answer (score 0):

“When you did …, I felt angry.”, “When you did …, I was pissed off.” (This way you own your own feelings). 
As opposed to “You made me angry.”, “You pissed me off.”.