# A casual word for the word complaint

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I will explain the scenario first.

*"I was trying to talk to my friend for many days. But he was busy with his own works. Then he messaged me that he would call me the next day for sure. But he didn't call me even the next day."*

I have a complaint with him for not calling.

But I am thinking that the word "complaint" is kind of a formal word. I would like to know about some casual word for it.

I tried Googling and found the synonyms quarrel, disagreement, gripe etc..

But we can't use those words in a casual way.

What are some thoughts on this? :)

Comment: I would suggest "I was rather miffed with him for not calling." https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miffed

Comment: In casual convos, I usually say [*beef*](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/beef).

Comment: @Ullas Can you clarify: *I have complaint to him for not calling.*? This is simply bad English. It is unclear whether you mean "I have complain**ed** [verb] to him for not calling" or I have **made a complaint** [noun] to him **about his/him** not calling."

Comment: Please note that ELU is generally not suited to English language learners at a level indicated by the way the question is written; our sister site, ELL, was set up largely for this reason.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul My dad uses "beef" as well. That's a good one.

Comment: It's probably old-fashioned, but there's also "to have a bone to pick with someone".

Comment: Not sure why *gripe* can't be used. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gripe) has it as "*informal* A minor complaint." @Ullas what's wrong with *gripe*? Did you find any other words which are listed as "informal"? (You did look in more than one dictionary or thesarus, I assume.)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Perhaps "beef" is too strong a word in this context? Certainly, people can have a beef with someone over very tiny things but usually, people wouldn't have a beef with someone over not having returned their calls.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Also 'beef' is somewhat out-of-date (very slangy for 1950's).

Comment: @Ullas *"But we can't use those words in a casual way."* Why not? All of those words seem very casual to me. Unless you can clearly explain why you don't think those words are *not*, there is no way of answering the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Synonym for "pissed off"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/synonym-for-pissed-off) (I'm ticked off at you.

I'm teed off at you.

I'm upset with you.

You've really irked me.

I'm peeved about this. // I'm angry / annoyed // ticked off // I am irritated with you
I am cross with you
I am mad at you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always say

> I ***am cross with my friend*** for not calling.

It is colloquial and it means

> Angry or annoyed with someone. In this usage, ***cross with*** is a set phrase followed by a noun or pronoun.
>
> - Of course ***I'm cross with you***—you lied to me! ([Free.dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cross+with))

However, you might object that this is rather a British phrase, and [rightly so](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am%20cross%20with%20you%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cam%20cross%20with%20you%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20cross%20with%20you%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20cross%20with%20you%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0).

There is an [American phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20am%20ticked%20off%3Aeng_us_2019%2CI%20am%20ticked%20off%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20ticked%20off%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0) that is used in informal situations:

> ***I am ticked off at my friend*** for not calling.

OR

> ***It's ticking me off*** (that) he didn't call.

***Tick off***

> *If you say that something ticks you off, you mean that it annoys you.*
> [US, informal]
>
> - She's still *ticked off* at him for brushing her off and going out with you instead.
> - I just think it's rude and *it's ticking me off*. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tick-off))

Comment: Though those suggestions may have the same social end, the meaning of these is varying levels of 'I am mad'. The OP asked for synonyms of 'complaint'. One can be mad and not complain, and one can complain without being mad.

Answer (score 0):

[Beef](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/beef) is an informal word that means *complaint*:

> My main beef about the job is that I have to work on Saturdays.

I don’t feel like it’s outdated as an expression. I use it — rarely — as do my friends and we are all in our 20s.